# Reinforcement Learning agent outputs a single value in continuous action space

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to have a PPO agent master a simple environment, consisting of a having to balance a ball over a bar to which it can apply torque. The agent has only one continuous action ie: the force it applies to one extremity of the bar (ranging from -1 to 1). I observe two failure modes:

- First, sometimes, despite my efforts, the agents diverges. The ratio values goes through the roof, and on analyze, all the weights in the network are NaNs.
- Second, and more annoying is the case that can be observed on the image, last column, first row,[see graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwCp3.png),  where the action value is described. Basically, the agent outputs nothing but this single value all along the episode. I can't understand why.

I tried to prevent it by using tanh between layers, but in vain. Could somebody help please ? Any tips on why an agent would completely focus on a single value ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you share the code you're using? Without that it's hard to see where it's going wrong. If I had to guess, I'd say you're not properly propagating rewards or not properly accounting for the terminal state.

Comment: Definitely. Here's a link to the self contained code ! https://github.com/Mehd6384/RL/tree/master/ContinuousPPO  Thanks !